# Need help with checking my proof related to equivalence mod n.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Let $n = a_ka_{k-1} \ldots a_1a_0$ be a natural number in base $10$. If $m = a_k + a_{k-1} + \ldots + a_1 + a_0$, then $n\equiv m\pmod n$.

$Proof:$

Let

$v = 0$, $x =a_k + a_{k-1} + \ldots + a_1$, $y = a_ka_{k-1} \ldots a_1a_0$, $z =a_0$.

Then,

claim $1$:

$0\equiv a_k + a_{k-1} + \ldots + a_1\pmod n$.

So, $n|0 - (a_k + a_{k-1} + \ldots + a_1)$  that is $\exists k \in \mathbb Z (kn = -(a_k + a_{k-1} + \ldots + a_1))$

Suppose $k = -1$. Then, claim $1$ is true.

and

claim $2$:

$a_ka_{k-1} \ldots a_1a_0\equiv a_0\pmod n$.

So, $n|a_ka_{k-1} \ldots a_1a_0 - a_0$ that is $\exists j \in \mathbb Z(jn = a_ka_{k-1} \ldots a_1a_0 - a_0 = a_0(a_ka_{k-1} \ldots a_1 - 1))$

Suppose $j = a_0$, then the claim $2$ is true.

From there it follows that

${v + y}\equiv x + z\pmod n$

$ a_ka_{k-1} \ldots a_1a_0\equiv a_k + a_{k-1} + \ldots + a_1 + a_0\pmod n$

Comment: I need to make something clear, so $n = a_k a_{k-1} \dots a_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, like $23, 2, 3\in \mathbb{N}?$

Comment: That's what I think. I copied that part off my textbook word for word.

Comment: Can't someone disprove this by just $23 \equiv 2 + 3 (\bmod 23) \iff 0 \equiv 5 (\bmod 23)$? Surely the implication is false right?

Comment: I should add that I was supposed to prove ${v + y}\equiv x + z\pmod 3$, but by mistake I proved(?) ${v + y}\equiv x + z\pmod n$.

Comment: I need to clarify something, what's $n$ at your last comment?

Comment: Now that you ask I am not sure. I really didn't think about that.

Comment: There appears to be a typo: almost certainly what's intended is $\, n\equiv m\ $ (mod $\color{#c00}{9}),\,$ not $ $ (mod $\,\color{#c00}n),\ $ i.e. *casting out nines*. Please double check the statement.

Comment: @ Bill Dubuque, would that make the proof correct or would I have to rewrite it? Also, how about proving the same statement but with mod $3$ instead of mod $n$? Can I do it directly or do I have to use indcution?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that $n\equiv m\pmod n$ is not a typo? I think that $n\equiv m\pmod n$ should be $n\equiv m\pmod 3$ or $n\equiv m\pmod 9$.

From your comment:

> Also, how about proving the same statement but with mod 3 instead of
>   mod n? Can I do it directly or do I have to use indcution?

You can prove it directly. Clearly, for all $k \in \mathbb Z^+$, $3 \mid 10^k - 1%$, so $10^k \equiv 1\pmod 3$. We also know that $n = (a_ka_{k-1} \ldots a_1a_0)_{10}$ can be written as the sum $n = 10^ka_k  + 10^{k-1}a_{k-1}  + \ldots 10a_1 + a_0$. Therefore, we can conclude that $n \equiv a_k + a_{k-1} + \ldots + a_1 + a_0\pmod 3$.